# NASM with C mixed

Tags: c, nasm

I've been working on a small OS for a while, and I've got all the assembler code I need. I can draw rectangles and stuff on the screen easily, but now I want to be able to work with this easier. I've been doing a lot of research, but nothing I've found helps. To give you a general idea of what I'm doing, here's a snippet of code / code I'd like to have

C Code

```
extern int drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height);

int loop(void) {
    drawRect(10, 10, 30, 30);
}
```

Assembler code

```
global drawRect

extern loop

drawRect:
    ; Rectangle code here
    ret
; Main OS loop
os_loop:
    ; My other code here
    call loop
    jmp os_loop ; Go back and loop again.
; ect..
```

But when I compile it and run it, I don't see my rectangle. If it helps you at all, I'm using the MikeOS kernel, and for compiling, I've just modified that compile code to this

```
#!/bin/sh

# This script assembles the MikeOS bootloader, kernel and programs
# with NASM, and then creates floppy and CD images (on Mac OS X)

# Only the root user can mount the floppy disk image as a virtual
# drive (loopback mounting), in order to copy across the files


echo ">>> BlueOS OS X build script - requires nasm and mkisofs"


echo ">>> Assembling bootloader..."

cd MyDirectory

nasm -O0 -f bin bootload/bootload.asm  -o bootload/bootload.bin || exit


echo ">>> Assembling BlueOS kernel and other files..."


cp disk_images/mikeos.flp disk_images/mikeos.dmg

nasm -O0 -f elf kernel.asm -o kernel.bin || exit

cd other

for i in *.asm
do
nasm -O0 -f elf $i -o `basename $i .asm`.bin || exit
done

echo ">>> Assembling C code..."

for i in *.c
do
gcc -ffreestanding -c $i -o `basename $i .c`.o || exit
done

cd ..

echo ">>> Creating floppy..."
cp disk_images/mikeos.flp disk_images/mikeos.dmg


echo ">>> Adding bootloader to floppy image..."

dd conv=notrunc if=bootload/bootload.bin of=disk_images/mikeos.dmg || exit


echo ">>> Copying BlueOS kernel and programs..."


dev=`hdid -nobrowse -nomount disk_images/mikeos.dmg`
mkdir tmp-loop && mount -t msdos ${dev} tmp-loop && cp kernel.bin tmp-loop/


echo ">>> Unmounting loopback floppy..."

diskutil unmount tmp-loop || exit
hdiutil detach ${dev}

rm -rf tmp-loop


echo ">>> BlueOS floppy image is disk_images/mikeos.dmg"


echo ">>> Creating CD-ROM ISO image..."

rm -f disk_images/mikeos.iso
mkisofs -quiet -V 'MIKEOS' -input-charset iso8859-1 -o disk_images/mikeos.iso -b mikeos.dmg disk_images/ || exit

echo '>>> Done!'
```

SIDE NOTES:
I'm on Mac OS X, if that makes a difference in anything.
SIDE QUESTION:
Is it possible to use C++ in place of C? I'm a fan of OOP.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing C and assembly depends on how your compiler is configured to handle parameters. If you're using gcc, it also depends on if you're building for 16/32/64 bits. Same goes for C++. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions for more.